# Time missing when running query using Oracle sqlplus

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, sql-scripts

I have the following script that I am running using sqlplus

```
set headsep off
set pagesize 0

spool 'c:\file.csv'
select to_char(trunc(created_date, 'hh')) AS reg_date, count(*)
from ORDERS.PRODUCT WHERE CREATED_DATE > TO_DATE('01/APR/2017','dd/mon/yyyy')
group by trunc(created_date, 'hh') ORDER BY reg_date DESC;
spool off
```

The output is missing the hours:

```
13-NOV-17,       400
13-NOV-17,       519
13-NOV-17,       126
13-NOV-17,       119
13-NOV-17,       171
13-NOV-17,       183
```

If I run the same script using SQL Developer, I get:

```
11/12/2017 17:00:00        396
11/12/2017 16:00:00        402
11/12/2017 15:00:00        459
11/12/2017 14:00:00        462
```

Why the difference? And how can I get the the hours when running using sqlplus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to the top of the script fixed the issue:

```
 alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm-dd-yyyy HH24:mi:ss';
```